# React - Infinite scrolling - child elemnts with dynamic heights

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm using react-infinite from (https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite), to have data loading when user scrolls.

The problem for me is that the child elements(inside the container), their height is dynamic.

This is the struct of the html:

```
<Infinite class="container" containerHeight={ContainerHeight} elementHeight={rowHieght}>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    ..
</Infinite>
```

So When I pass the infinite the rowHeight and the containerHeight I calculate them dynamiclly.

The problem is that the childs can have different heights(meaning 1 child can have a height of 100, white the second can has 300).

That makes the infinite scrolling to get stuck sometimes.

Is that a possible scenario for infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [document](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite#elements-of-varying-heights), you can set like this:

```
<Infinite containerHeight={200} elementHeight={[111, 252, 143]}>
    <div className="111-px"/>
    <div className="252-px"/>
    <div className="143-px"/>
</Infinite>
```